# SQL - only select results that do not have a specific status value in a corresponding table

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables, and I only want to get the Student IDs where they have perfect attendance for all months (they do not have a PerfectAttendance value of N for any month). These tables will have hundreds of millions of rows, so I was trying to come up with an approach that doesn't require a full separate subquery. If anyone has any recommendations, please let me know:

Table `Student`:

```
ID  Name
------------
1   A
2   B
```

Table `Attendance`:

```
ID  Month   PerfectAttendance
---------------------------------
1   1   Y
1   2   Y
1   3   Y
1   4   Y
1   5   Y
1   6   Y
1   7   Y
1   8   Y
1   9   Y
1   10  Y
1   11  Y
1   12  Y
2   1   Y
2   2   Y
2   3   Y
2   4   Y
2   5   Y
2   6   Y
2   7   Y
2   8   Y
2   9   Y
2   10  Y
2   11  Y
2   12  N
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this one, OP?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Student S
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Attendance
                 WHERE PerfectAttendance = 'N'
                 AND ID = S.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 12 records per student in attendance table based on your data , you can do it with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT S.ID, S.NAME
FROM Student S
JOIN Attendance A
on S.ID = A.ID
AND A.PerfectAttendance = 'Y'
GROUP BY S.ID, S.NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for this would be to query the table and get the number of months that each student has perfect attendance. Once you've done that, you can filter on the count being 12 (since there are twelve months).

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, COUNT(*) AS numPerfectMonths
FROM student s JOIN attendence a ON s.id = a.id
WHERE a.perfectAttendance = 'Y'
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 12;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6abeb/2) for you.

**EDIT**
I made the assumption you will have 12 rows for each student. However, let's say you ran this in October and you want to see which students have a perfect attendance up to that point. You can use a subquery to pull for students without perfect attendance, and filter them out using `NOT IN` like so:

```
SELECT id
FROM student
WHERE id 
NOT IN(SELECT s.id
    FROM student s JOIN attendance a ON s.id = a.id
    WHERE a.perfectAttendance = 'N'
    GROUP BY s.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0);
```

Have an updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6abeb). To test this one, try deleting one of the rows for id number 1, and you'll still see that they are returned with perfect attendance.

Answer (score 0):

I think Lamak's answer is probably the clearest and best-performing, but here is another variation on the GROUP BY method suggested by others, when you don't specifically look for a total of 12 months:

```
;WITH PerfectAttendance AS (
    SELECT  a.id
    FROM    Attendance a
    GROUP BY a.id
    HAVING MIN(a.PerfectAttendance) = 'Y'
)
SELECT  s.id, s.Name
FROM    PerfectAttendance p
        JOIN Student s ON p.id = s.id;
```

Comment: Instead of that `CASE` you could just do `HAVING MIN(PerfectAttendance) = 'Y'`